# How to fix wakeup problem such as display artefacts on nvidia proprietary on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

My setup is: Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.8.0-45, Nvidia proprietary drivers 375.39 from ppa on GeForce GTX 960, Display 1680x1050

The problem is when I wakeup from suspend. The windows have border with artefacts like on picture. The only solution is to restart lightdm service by:

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service #restart Xserver
```

but this kills my open apps. Open source drivers works fine.

[image: Printscreen after wakeup]

Comment: Solved by Nvidia drivers downgrade to 370.28